# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS keeps logging me out after a few seconds after coming out of standy by

Tags: 18.04

My Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS keeps logging me out after a few seconds after coming out of standy by. 
(Razer Blade, Gaming Laptop (Intel i7-7700HQ, 16GB RAM, 1TB SSD, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060)

I close the laptop and after opening it and logging back in it kicks me back out to the log in screen and the immediatly goes back into stand by.

So far I have tried updating my log in manager, different kernels, I reinstalled Ubuntu and updatet my BIOS. 
I am sorta out of ideas now.

Anybody have the same problem and already fixed it? I would be forever grateful. It pretty much unusable as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RazerBlade) helpful.

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 22.04 on a Razor Blade gaming laptop. I resolved it by following the instructions from the link above under the "Suspend" header:

> The OS does not detect that the lid has been opened if the laptop is
> suspended. This can be fixed through the following modification:
>
> 1. Edit the default grub config:
>
>    sudo nano /etc/default/grub
> 2. Add button.lid_init_state=open to the end of the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT option, like this:
>
>    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash button.lid_init_state=open"
> 3. Run the following command to update grub one you are done:
>
>    sudo update-grub